# show echo inside an array apostrophe

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I wish to echo a function inside the array apostrophe. 
My function should come instead of the "about" phrase:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'about' )); ?>
```

This is my function:

```
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpshed_textfield', true );
```

I have tried doing this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpshed_textfield', true ); )); ?>
```

and this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => '.'echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpshed_textfield', true );'.' )); ?>
```

and also using a function:

```
<?php function writeMsg() {
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpshed_textfield', true );
}
writeMsg(); 
 ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => $writeMsg )); ?>
```

But none of this works. Any ideas ?

Comment: You don't want to `echo` it...you just want its `return` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( 
    array(
        'menu' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpshed_textfield', true ) 
    )
);
```

In order for this to work, your wpshed_textfield metafield has to be the name, id or slug of a menu you registered.

Answer (score 0):

```
or if you want to use your custom function
```

function writeMsg() {

return get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpshed_textfield', true );

}
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => writeMsg() ));